# How do I get rid of vertical scrollbar on video in anythingslider?

Tags: video, scrollbar, anythingslider

I have a simple build of anythingSlider in development. Everything is fine so far except when I try and place a video element in the midst of static images within the same slider.

There is a vertical scrollbar that appears only during the video slide. Any suggestions on how to get rid of this?

In an earlier attempt, I reduced the size of the video (to half its current viewing size compared to what can be viewed on the link below), but the scrollbar remained - it just got smaller with everything else.

Thanks for any input you may have.

link:
http://sitedev.lcadfiles.com/branding_rad.html

Answer (score 0):

I see that each panel has a set height of 580x450, but really that gets ignored when the `resizeContents` option is `false`. The panel will resize to fit its content. I see the video size doesn't match the intended panel size:

```
<video id="inslide" width="580" height="320" controls="" loop="" poster="../img/radians-bran.jpg" preload="auto" >
```

So the easiest option would be to set the `resizeContents` option to `true` OR, change `overflow-y` to `hidden` in the css:

```
#slider, #slider li {
  width: 580px;
  height: 450px;
  list-style: none;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

but doing so would hide all but the first image if the user has javascript disabled.

Comment: Thanks. Went with the overflow-y to "hidden" option... Resizing the video created a quality loss. If a user has javascript disabled they aren't going to see our site as intended anyway - not just in this instance.